# How many Volley request queues should be maintained?

Tags: android, android-volley

Currently I am maintaining one static Volley request queue as described here:

[Instantiating core Volley objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336434/instantiating-core-volley-objects)

```
  private static RequestQueue mReqQueue;
```

Should there be one and only one static request queue per app?  What is the harm in having more than one?  for example what if I wanted one request queue just to process twitter requests.  And another one for everything else like authentication, image retrieval etc.

Answer (score 14):

I think Ficus Kirkpatrick said somewhere in [his presentation on Volley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) that optimally, there is only one `RequestQueue`.

If most of your activities, services and receivers make use of Volley, and you do a lot of switching between them, it makes sense to define a singleton `RequestQueue` in your `Application` object so that you don't have to instantiate a new `RequestQueue` in every acticity / service / receiver `onCreate`.

However, if you have a lot of activities, and use Volley in only one of them for one request, then you might be better off defining the `RequestQueue` in just that `Activity`, or it'll get instantiated in the activities in which you don't use it. This shouldn't hurt functionality, but could hurt memory-wise.

---

## EDIT:

In the volley user group, Ficus said:

> RequestQueues are pretty cheap (mostly just threads). We use more than one in our app in order to segregate caches.

Which tells us that it's also a valid use case to use multiple `RequestQueues` if you need to have separate caches.

Comment: But what if you switched to another Activity, and want to pause the request in the previouse Activity, load the new request firstly?

Comment: This is a breach of what an Activity should do. If you want to be able to cancel an ongoing download across Activities, you should perform the download in a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).