# Multiple RequestQueue in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I read multiple blog and android developer site  about volley request queue. All we use Single RequestQueue through in application . But i want to know what if i use multiple queue in an application  and how it works . Will it degrade and affect working

Comment: It's better to have a single RequestQueue. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709347/how-many-volley-request-queues-should-be-maintained

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many Volley request queues should be maintained?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709347/how-many-volley-request-queues-should-be-maintained)