# Execute single request using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

**Basic explanation**
I'm currently using Volley for a part of my application.
Since I'm already using it and enjoying the wise HTTP requests, I was wondering if there's a way to make a Volley.Request without a RequestQueue.

I've been searching the web for a while, even going through Volley's source, Google I/O.

**Further explanation:** I have another Activity which onCreate I'd like to fetch data about it. I wanted to execute only one Request, I don't need the entire Queue..

I thought of some implementations:

 1. make a Singleton class with RequestQueue that I'll call add from each Activity I need (I don't think that's the best idea..).

2. Use RequestQueue in every Activity I need (I also don't think it's the best idea).

3. Create my own Request class and implement my own HTTP execute.

4. according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336434/instantiating-core-volley-objects?rq=1), I can instantiate the RequestQueue with the Application and just add to queue from each Activity.. but since the Request won't happen immidiately (so I believe), I don't think that's the best idea - please correct me if I'm wrong.

**My question is:** is there a way to asynchronously start a single Request without RequestQueue? if not, which is the best option from my implementations? if none, please suggest another.

Thank you.

Comment: I use a singelton application. The application class contains the queue. Works.

Comment: Requests run as soon as they get in the queue. Volley also handles parallelism. Just use your forth option, it's your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

1. is right option. Remember that you can place onResponse at the same activity / code where the request is and handle asynchronous behaviour this way.